# MVC Edit view with pictures doesn't work! Creates a new one instead of overtiring existing one selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

just say sorry for the question as there is tones of information regarding upload images using MVC and SQL server but the thing is I've got this problem for 3 days and I couldn't find anything specific.

I've got my MVC project with the Edit view and the option to upload an image and display it, the problem is when you Save Changes is creating a new row on my table with the uploaded picture and the image from the row selected is gone, but what I want is override the existing picture in the row selected with the new one uploaded (basically edit the whole row including the picture instead of messing around with new rows). I guess the problem is in my controller but every time I try something new just doesn't work. Thanks!

HomeController:

```
 public JsonResult ImageUpload(ImageViewModel model)
    {
        ImageDatabaseEntities6 db = new ImageDatabaseEntities6();
        int imgId = 0;
        var file = model.ImageFile;
        byte[] imagebyte = null;
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/UploadImage/" + file.FileName));
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            imagebyte = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
            imageData img = new imageData();
            img.ImageTitle = file.FileName;
            img.ImageByte = imagebyte;
            img.ImagePath = "/UploadImage/" + file.FileName;
            db.imageDatas.Add(img);
            db.SaveChanges();
            imgId = img.ImageId;
        }
        return Json(jobs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult DisplayingImage(int imgid)
    {
        ImageDatabaseEntities6 db = new ImageDatabaseEntities6();

        var img = db.imageDatas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ImageId == imgid);
        return File(img.ImageByte, "image/jpg");
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? ImageId)
    {
        if (ImageId == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

       imageData jobs = db.imageDatas.Find(ImageId);

        if (jobs == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(jobs);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(imageData jobs)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(jobs).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(jobs);
    }
```

Edit View:

```
 @model JobsManagerApp.Models.imageData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" height="140" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" id="SelectImage" /><br />
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="UploadImage()">Upload</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 thumbnail" id="UploadedImage"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">         
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Type of Job")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TypeOfJob)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Tools Needed")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToolsNeeded)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Profit")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Profit)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Expenses less than five miles")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpensesLessThanFiveMiles)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Expenses less than ten miles")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpenseslessThanTenMiles)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Expenses less than twenty miles")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpensesLessThanTwentyMiles)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Expenses less than thirty miles")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpensesLessThanThirtyMiles)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Materials")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Materials)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Estimate duration")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstimateDuration)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayName("Number of employees")
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EstimateNofEmployees)
        </dd>
</dl>

<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var UploadImage = function () {
        var file = $("#SelectImage").get(0).files;
        var data = new FormData;
        data.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ImageUpload",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (imgID) {
                $("#UploadedImage").append('<img src="/Home/DisplayingImage?imgID=' + imgID + '"class=img-responsive  thimbnail"/>');
            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")enter code here
```

Comment: You need to define "just doesn't work". What happens or doesn't happen the way you expect?

Comment: Thanks you're right that will help people with the same problem using the search engine

Comment: So you agree that you need to fix your question yet you do nothing about it? Good luck!!!

Comment: I changed it again, twice already, this time I wrote DOESN'T WORK and I tryed to be specific, sorry this is my second post, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: The issue with saying "It doesn't work" is that it tells us you have put in little to no effort to solving the problem yourself. You may find this article helpful in the future http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: When you take your car to the shop you usually tell the guy what is wrong with your car. You don't take it in, toss them the keys and say "my car isn't working". What isn't working? Does it give you an error? Does it not update? Does it turn off the lights in the room?

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the row if it already exists or insert a new row if it doesn't, change `db.imageDatas.Add(img);` to `db.imageDatas.AddOrUpdate(id => id.ImageTitle, img);` and add `using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;` to the top of your file.

You'll then need to get the imageData `ImageID` from the database and can replace `imgId = img.ImageId;` with `imgId = db.imageDatas.FirstOrDefault(id => id.ImageTitle == img.ImageTitle);`.

Comment: I just answered you in a comment below